# if there is a space then starting letter should be capital

Tags: sql-server-2017

I have a column data like this

```
column
--------------
i am spiderman
i am superman
this is raj
```

If there is a space, then the first letter should be capitalized:

```
select 
    @a as [Normal text],
    upper(left(@a, 1)) + lower(substring(@a, 2, len(@a))) as [Capitalize first letter only]
```

Results:

```
column
----------
i Am Spiderman
i Am Superman
this Is Raj
```

Answer (score 1):

We can try using SQL Server's enhanced `LIKE` here to check if the first letter be a lowercase letter:

```
SELECT
    col AS input,
    CASE WHEN col LIKE '[a-z] %'
         THEN UPPER(LEFT(col, 1)) + RIGHT(col, LEN(col-1))
         ELSE col END AS output
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

Comment: @codeERR Apologies...after testing I discovered a small typo which I have now corrected.

Comment: i need every starting letter should be capital after space

Comment: You can't easily do this with SQL Server.  You need regex replacement, which SQL Server doesn't support.

Comment: then how can do this

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
   var str = "I am the king";
   var capitalizedFirstLetter = 
   str.split(/\s/).map(word=>word[0].toUpperCase()+word.slice(1));
   var fullSentence = capitalizedFirstLetter.join(' ');
   console.log(fullSentence);
```

First we split the sentence into words and then use a map function to convert the first letter to uppercase and remove the last lowercase letter using the slice function. After that we use the join function to join the array again in a sentence. Hope it helps!

Comment: if i want to do for whole column data what should i do

Comment: You can iterate over each column in the frontend using JavaScript map function if you know how to send data to frontend from SQL database in a array.

Comment: Sorry I thought you would want to convert it in displaying it to users, For SQL I will look up but I am not a SQL expert tbh....